# ASP.NET MVC: How to pass parameter between controllers before and after post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have below controllers:

```
// GET: /MaterialPaymentRequestSbuItem/CreateChild
public ActionResult CreateChild(int? parentId)
{
    if (parentId==null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var parenetRequest = (from request in db.MaterialPaymentRequests
        where request.Id==(int)parentId
        select request);

    ViewBag.MaterialPaymentRequestId = new SelectList(parenetRequest, "Id", "Description", (int)parentId);
    ViewBag.ParentID = parentId;
    if (parenetRequest!=null && parenetRequest.First()!=null)
        ViewBag.ParentTitle = parenetRequest.First().Description;

    return View();
}

// POST: /MaterialPaymentRequestSbuItem/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateChild([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Unit,UnitPrice,MaterialPaymentRequestId,Quantity")] MaterialPaymentRequestSubItem materialpaymentrequestsubitem)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            db.MaterialPaymentRequestSubItems.Add(materialpaymentrequestsubitem);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
        updateTotalPriceOfParentPaymentRequest(db, db.MaterialPaymentRequests.Find(materialpaymentrequestsubitem.MaterialPaymentRequestId));
        return RedirectToAction("List", new { id = materialpaymentrequestsubitem.MaterialPaymentRequestId });
    }

    ViewBag.MaterialPaymentRequestId = new SelectList(db.PaymentRequests, "Id", "Description", materialpaymentrequestsubitem.MaterialPaymentRequestId);
    //need to becheked
    ViewBag.ParentID = materialpaymentrequestsubitem.MaterialPaymentRequestId;
    if (Request != null && Request["parentID"] != null)
    {
        try
        {
            int id = Int32.Parse(Request["parentID"]);
            ViewBag.ParentTitle = db.MaterialPaymentRequests.Find(id).Description;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
    return View(materialpaymentrequestsubitem);
}
```

My main problem is that user is allowed to select model.MaterialPaymentRequestId from drop-down and he/she may leave it with no value selected. `MaterialPaymentRequestId` is used in first controller (befor post) to find Parent title from db and pass it to view using ViewBag, however if user does not select `MaterialPaymentRequestId` dropdown items, after postback, I lost `MaterialPaymentRequestId`. Currently I read `Request` variable and look inside url to find parameters to lookup for parentID.
My url calls are like http://localhost:46813/Admin/MaterialPaymentRequestSbuItem/CreateChild?parentId=23.

However this practice seems like a bad practice than I cannot pass v variable between two controller methods a process like this:

Controller method(get) ---> View ---> Controller method(post)

Currently I feel a bit stuck in MVC!

Comment: Have you tried to using TempData instead of ViewBag check this link for detail https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

i hope i got your point right, you can use an `@Html.hiddenfor(model => model.ParentId)` in your view it will store `ParentId` value from query string and when user submits form will be posted to POST method so you dont need to look into url to get it. use a viewmodel with ParentId property and do as below

```
public class MaterialPaymentsViewModel {
    //other properties
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult CreateChild(int? parentId)
{
    var model = new MaterialPaymentsViewModel{ParentId = parentId};
    //other stuff

    return View(model);
}

//View

@using (Html.beginform()){
//
@html.hiddenfor(m => m.ParentId)
//submit
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateChild(MaterialPaymentsViewModel  model)
{
    if(model.ParentId != null)
{
 //
}
  //
}
```